# Confused by self["name"] = filename

Tags: python, self

I'm currently reading this amazing book called "Dive into Python". Up to now everything has made sense to me, but the following method has left me with some questions. Its in the chapter about initializing classes:

```
class FileInfo(UserDict):
    "store file metadata"
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        UserDict.__init__(self)
        self["name"] = filename
```

It's only the last line I don't get. The way I see it at the moment, the calling object has a list, whose item "name" is assigned the value of the argument passed. But this doesn't make sense to me, since I thought that you can only access list indices by integers.
The book says the following about this line: "You're assigning the argument filename as the value of this object's name key." Is the name key another variable that every object defines (like **doc**)? And if yes, why can it be accessed like that?

Comment: Dive into Python is a great free book!

Comment: Wow - 5 answers in less than 5 minutes..

Comment: @Tim McNamara My first answer about Python, by the way.

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thanks to all of you for your answers, now it makes sense! I got so hung up on self["name"] being a list, that I expected some sort of "python-magic" instead of looking at the big picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[...]` isn't just for lists. Any type can support it, and the index doesn't necessarily have to be an integer. `self` is the current object, which according to your code derives from `UserDict`, which supports the [item manipulation methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Answer (score 2):

You're extending a dictionary, by doing `class FileInfo(UserDict)`, that's why you can reference to the key doing `self['name'] = filename`

Answer (score 2):

The class inherits from `UserDict` which I presume is a dict-like class. For all subclasses of dicts (which keeps the dict interface intact), you can treat `self` as a dict, which is why you can do `self[key] = value`

Answer (score 2):

Since your class derives from [UserDict](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html), it inherits a [`__getitem__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method that takes an arbitrary key, not just an integer:

```
self["name"] = filename  # Associate the filename with the "name" key.
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the `self` object is a subclass of `UserDict`, which is a form of hash table (known as a dictionary or `dict` in Python). The last line is simply creating a key `"name"` to the filename.